# Uploading files though Alamofire and retrieve it server side with Slim PHP

Tags: php, swift, alamofire, slim

I tried to solved an issue regarding file upload with `Alamofire` ([Link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)) (Swift 3.0) and retrieving them server-side using `Slim PHP` ([Link](https://www.slimframework.com)) micro framework.

I'm trying to upload picture taken from the iPhone using

```swift
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ 
multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append("value".data(/* ... */)!, withName :"key")

   var idx = 1;
   for imageRepresentation in imageData {
       let pictureName = "pictures[]"
       multipartFormData.append(imageRepresentation, withName: pictureName, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
       idx += 1
   }

 },
 to: uploadUrl,
 method:.post,
 headers: httpHeaders,
 encodingCompletion: /* ... */
```

Here i'm almost sure that this script is working fine because when I hit `https://httpbin.org/post` I get back the encoded `data base 64` image I've uploaded, so I'm quite sure that the issue comes from my server side code.

So, as I said, I'm using **Slim PHP** ([Link](https://www.slimframework.com)) server side with this route

```php
$this->post('/upload', function ($request, $response, $args) {

        $request->getParsedBody(); //null
        $request->getQueryParams(); // []
        $request->getBody(); // {}
        $request->getUploadedFiles(); // []

        return /*Some JSON */

    })->setName('upload');
```

Did I miss something ? Is there something I didn't understand ?
I already tried

- [Multipart/form-data example in slim micro framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192698/multipart-form-data-example-in-slim-micro-framework)
- https://akrabat.com/psr-7-file-uploads-in-slim-3/

And the most weird thing is that the script works like a charm when executed from Paw API Explorer

Any help would be really appreciated ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Uploading the image selected from photo library

In Swift 3 and Alamofire 4

Here is the Full Implementation of how to upload using Alamofire

1. Add the Following to your ViewController Class:

   `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`
2. Create A Button:

First Create a button and implement the Following method in it for picker view

```
@IBAction func btnSelectProfileImageClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    ImagePicker.delegate = self
    ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    
    self.present(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
}
```

3. Then Implement the following UIPicker Methods:

   ```
   func imagePickerController( _ picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String : Any] )
   {Imgprofile.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}
   ```
4. Make Another Button Which Passes the data to URL using Alamofire and Give an `@IBAction` outlet to it to it :

Enter Following Data to it

```
 @IBAction func btnUpdateProfileSelected(_ sender: Any) {
    
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.Imgprofile.image!, 1)!, withName: "Prescription", fileName: "Profile_Image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, to:" Your URL Here where You want to Upload")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            print(result)
            
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print(progress)
            })
            
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //print response.result
                print(response);
            }
            
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats all

Hope This helps

> For **Full sample code** or any doubts please comment. I will provide you
> the sample code for this. Which Includes the Fetching as well as
> upload data using Alamofire.

Thanks

Comment: I already know that. 
The issue is located on the `Content-type` of Alamofire regarding file upload.